# Is this set, defined in terms of an irreducible representation, closed under inverses?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let $ H $ be an irreducible finite subgroup of $ \GL(n,\mathbb{C}) $. Define $ N^r(H) $ inductively by
$$
N^{r+1}(H)=\{ g \in \GL(n,\mathbb{C}): g H g^{-1} \subset N^r(H) \} 
$$
starting from $ N^1(H):= H $.

Note that, since $ H $ is finite, the "semi-normalizer" $ N^2(H) $ is just the normalizer of $ H $ (see comment from LSpice). And thus is closed under inverses. But for $ r \geq 3 $ the set $ N^r(H) $ is generally not a group.

My question: Is $ N^r(H) $ closed under inverses?

The answer appears to be yes for $ n=2 $ (and is yes trivially for $ n=1 $ since then $ N^r(H)=\GL(1,\mathbb{C}) $ for all $ r \geq 2 $).

Context:

This construction is used for a naturally occurring object called the Clifford hierarchy which appears in quantum computing. For example, the (single qubit) Clifford hierarchy is the case where $ n=2 $ and $ H= \left\langle \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \right\rangle $ is the single qubit Pauli group.

For $ H $ infinite there are many counterexamples. There is a counterexample with reducible $ H $ due to Arturo Magidin in [this MathSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4807084)   with $ H = \left\{\left.\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & m\\
0 & 1\end{array}\right)\in G\ \right|\ m\in\mathbb{Z}\right\} $ where $ x = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 0\\
0 & 1\end{array}\right) $ is in $ N^2(H) $ but $ x^{-1} $ is not.

And there is a counterexample for infinite $ H $ with $ H $ irreducible given by Moishe Kohen in the answer to [this MathSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4811329/758507)

More generally we can consider representations over fields other than $ \mathbb{C} $.

Some thoughts: If $ H $ is projectively self-normalizing (meaning the normalizer is just $ H $ with scalar matrices) then clearly the hierarchy $ N^r(H) $ is closed under inverses because $ N^r(H)=<H,\mathbb{C}^\times I > $ for all $ r \geq 2 $. This applies to all projectively self-normalizing subgroups $ H $ of $ GL(n,\mathbb{C}) $, including all $ H $ such that $ H/Z(H) $ is a maximal finite subgroup of $ PGL(n,\mathbb{C}) $ (since irreducible finite subgroups always have a [projectively finite normalizer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4570062/condition-for-normalizer-to-be-finite)).  For example all subgroups for $ n=1 $. And the subgroups $ H=2.A_5 $ and $ H=2.S_4 $ for $ n=2 $.

Comment: I think the norm (as opposed to the normaliser ) is that it is better to avoid editorialising, like "interesting", "difficult", etc., in the title (and preferably in the body), so I edited out "interesting".

Comment: @LSpice +1 good point, you are kind and wise as always!

Comment: I think you mean that $N^3(H)$, not the normaliser $N^2(H)$, might fail to be closed under inverses.  Is your revised expectation due to the counterexamples you mention, or some other evidence or hunch?

Comment: @LSpice I really do mean $ N^2(H) $ fails to be closed under inverses! The subtle thing here is that there is a containment not an equality in the condition $ gHg^{-1} \subset N^r(H) $ so if $ H $ is infinite then even for $ r=1 $ the containment $ gHg^{-1} \subset H=N^1(H) $ can be proper! So although when $ H $ is finite then $ N^2(H) $ is the normalizer, when $ H $ is infinite then $ N^2(H) $ is just some set that (properly) contains the normalizer.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1191260), ah, I see.  I was thinking, as in @YCor's now-deleted answer, of the algebraic case, where one can show with finite invariants (dimension and number of components) that what I guess should be called the "semi-normalizer" $N^2(H)$ is actually the normalizer; but now I take your point.  For example, one could take $\tilde H$ to be the integer-indexed sequences of reals and $H$ to be the subgroup of $\tilde H$ that vanishes on negative integers, and put $G = \langle\sigma\rangle \ltimes \tilde H$, where $\sigma$ is the right shift.

Comment: Can we understand a simple case? E.g. take $H= S_4$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^3 \simeq \{ (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4: x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 0\}$ by permuting variables (how's that called? Standard?). I was wondering if one can 'classify' sets $X$ that satisfy $g H g^{-1} \subset X$ iff $g^{-1} H g \subset X$

Comment: @AndreaMarino I believe that the irreducible $ H=S_4 $ subgroup of $ GL(3,\mathbb{C}) $ you describe is essentially self-normalizing so the hierarchy immediately terminates with $ N^r(H)= <H,\mathbb{C}^\times I> $ for all $ r \geq 2 $

Comment: You are right. Not sure is a good way to prosecute, but to keep things small one could try to address the more general problem of describing which $X$ has the property I mentioned. By the way, do you have any hints about why this should hold? From a non-expert perspective, it seems like a pretty un-motivated property!

Comment: It fails to be closed under inverse if you drop the irreducibility assumption.

Comment: @MoisheKohan That sounds right, do you have a particular example in mind?

Comment: Yes, in SL(2,C).

Comment: @MoisheKohan would you be willing to share the specifics of this example, perhaps posted as an answer if it is too long for a comment?

Comment: OK, I will add an answer later.

Comment: @MoisheKohan don't want to rush you but if you post in the next 22 hours I can award you the bounty!

Comment: Sorry, I found a mistake in my example.

Comment: ah ok, no worries